# Multi band images in land prediction using tensorflow/pytorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I have patch of land and this patch of land  I have 2 satellite images  for it . The 1st one is is tiff format and contain the the land elevation and the 2nd satellite image which is in rgb format is the picture of that patch of land from above. Furthermore, I learned about transfer learning etc using pytorch and tensorflow.

Now the goal is to predict the type of the land (hills, valley, ridge...etc.) using shapes, colors, surface elevation, from those images.

Now my steps are:

1. Merging the Elevation band with rbg 3 bands to make three bands and we can have and array of depth of 4.
2. The labels corresponding to those 2 satellite images are in vector shapes and those vectors can be transferred to raster format. But for deep learning they require labels in certain format with certain folder structure.
3. Is using the 3 bands of the rgb on transfer learning because from what I heard is only work on rgb images and then use normal model on the elevation band (array) to predict land type.
4. fuse everything in step 3 to predict land type.

My question is how to make this possible.